# How to Loop Through Every OTHER Column Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to compare dates in the chart pictured. I want to compare cells 1 and 2 and if the dates are the same then move to 3 and 4 and do the same comparison and then move to 5 and 6 and so on. If the dates are different I want to add 1 to a counter. Then at the end of each row I need to fill the cell at the end of the row with the 0 in it currently with the counter value and then reset the counter and move to the next row and so on. so the circled counter should read 1 because there is one pair of different dates. The code i have so far is attached. Currently it tells me "Object required" at Set CompD1. Pretty new to this so any help is appreciated. 
[image]

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim AdjPln As Integer
Dim CompD1 As Range
Dim CompD2 As Range
Dim cRow As Integer

For i = 0 To 49

AdjPln = 0

cRow = i + 13

    For j = 0 To 9
    Set CompD1 = Cells(cRow, j + 5).value
    Set CompD2 = Cells(cRow, j + 6).value
        If CompD1 = CompD2 Then
            j = j + 2
        Else
            AdjPln = AdjPln + 1
            j = j + 2
        End If

    Next j

Cells(cRow, 24) = AdjPln

Stop
Next i
```

Comment: Work with [Range.RowDifferences method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.rowdifferences)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `j` loop is the issue when you tried to change the value with the formula to increment by 2 instead of 1. When you went to loop by increments other than one, you can use the `Step` option. In your case, you want to loop `j` by 2 so `Step 2`. You can also do negative if that is useful.

See if this works:

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, AdjPln As Integer, cRow As Integer

For i = 0 To 49

AdjPln = 0

cRow = i + 13

 For j = 0 To 9 Step 2

    If Cells(cRow, j + 5).Value <> Cells(cRow, j + 6).Value Then

        AdjPln = AdjPln + 1

    End If

 Next j

Cells(cRow, 24) = AdjPln

Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this could be done with a simple formula. Put this in X13 and drag down.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((E13:U13<>F13:V13)*(E13:U13<>"")*(F13:V13<>"")*ISODD(COLUMN(E13:U13)))
```